# Clean data before mongoDB insert

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I want to prevent the database from storing empty fields. When I update my collection, input fields that have been left blank insert `""`. I don't want this to happen. I only want the collection to save the field if the field has data in it.

Step 1: `Existing document state when the form first loads`

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {
     careerHistoryPositions: [
       {
         company: '',
         uniqueId: uniqueId,
         title: '',
       }
     ]
   };

   this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
 }
```

Step 2: `Show new data to update`

```
this.setState = {
     careerHistoryPositions: [
       {
         uniqueId: "1",
         company: "Company 1",
         title: "Title 1",
       }
       {
         uniqueId: "2",
         company: "",
         title: "Title 2",
       }
     ]
   };
```

In step 2, **the second position**, company is blank but it appears in setState as `""`. When I run an update to push the data into the collection, I don't want `company: ""` to be stored in the collection because the field is empty. I want it to be omitted.

Step 3: `How I'm pushing it into the database`

```
handleFormSubmit(event) {

   ProfileCandidate.update({
     _id: this.state.profileCandidateCollectionId
   }, {
     $unset: {
       'careerHistoryPositions': {}
     }
   })

   this.state.careerHistoryPositions.map((position) => {
     ProfileCandidate.update({
       _id: this.state.profileCandidateCollectionId
     }, {
       $push: {
         'careerHistoryPositions': {
           company: position.company,
           uniqueId: position.uniqueId,
           title: position.title,
         }
       }
     });
   }
 }
```

Outcome: `How the collection currently looks`

```
{
  "_id": "BoDb4Zztq7n3evTqG",
  "careerHistoryPositions": [
    {
      "uniqueId": 1,
      "company": "Company 1",
      "title": "Title 1",
    }
    {
      "uniqueId": 2,
      "company": "",
      "title": "Title 2",
    }
  ]
}
```

**Desired Collection Outcome**

```
{
  "_id": "BoDb4Zztq7n3evTqG",
  "careerHistoryPositions": [
    {
      "uniqueId": 1,
      "company": "Company 1",
      "title": "Title 1",
    }
    {
      "uniqueId": 2,
      "title": "Title 2",
    }
  ]
}
```

In my `desired collection outcome` the second object doesn't contain `company` because there was no data to save in the first place.

How do you do this?

Comment: Unclear what you mean. You are using `$push` here which "appends to an array". Are you expecting "singular data" instead? And therefore it should not be an array. Show an initial state of the document and then the altered state as an example. That would be much clearer as an explanation than your present code, which "may" be doing the wrong thing entirely.

Comment: There can be multiple companies in this situation. As I mentioned when I run the function to update the collection using `$push` the fields that are blank are saved to the database with `""`.  I've updated the example to include what the collection looks like when the form contains blank input fields.

Comment: You cannot "update" and "add to" an array at the same time. You **CAN** update this "single" array item and replace it with some actual data though. Like I said, your question is very unclear because you are trying to explain it by using operations you do not fully understand. Best to show by example instead. Also explain why this needs to be an array in the first place. Since I do not see any clear reason why the data should even be contained in an array.

Comment: Hi @NeilLunn, sorry for the confusion. To be honest I'm not sure how else to explain this. This needs to be an array because the user can have multiple careerHistoryPositions. SEE UPDATE.

Comment: Honestly this is still "clear as mud" and still the main reason why is you are telling us what your code "does/you want it to do" instead of "simply describing the process". So what actually needs to happen? Are you trying to "swap" something that has an empty "company" field with other data? Are you trying to "add new data"? Are you trying to "replace all data"? Because the way your question reads to start saying one thing and then contradict with another. **INSTEAD**. 1. Start with your existing document state. 2. Show new data to update. 3. Show new updated state. Can't miss.

Comment: @NeilLunn, I've completely rewritten the question following your suggestion. Hopefully, this is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [aldeed:meteor-collection2-core](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2-core) in conjunction with [simpl-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema) it will remove empty strings for you automatically. Collection2 is quite useful, it nicely augments simpl-schema.

Otherwise you can add an [autoValue](https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema#autovalue) to the schema for these string fields as follows:

```
autoValue(){
  if ( this.isSet && !this.value.length ) this.unset();
}
```

Which basically says "if the modifier is trying to set this field to a zero-length value then remove it from the modifier."

Comment: Hi @MichelFloyd, Thanks for this. I'm using collection2 and simple-schema. I think my issues might be related to bug. Since you seem to bit of a guru, could you take a look at the link below and confirm if it's a bug.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45180249/array-of-objects-passes-validation-but-doesnt-update-collection?noredirect=1#comment77355469_45180249