# Array of objects passes validation but doesn't update collection

Tags: meteor, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

My update method is passing the simple-schema validation test however it isn't updating my collection. I'm updating an array of objects.

Example: `array`

```js
var arrayTest = [ 
  { 
    company: 'sdsd',
    uniqueId: 1500431892902,
    title: '',
    description: '',
    startDateMonth: '',
    startDateYear: '',
    endDateMonth: '',
    endDateYear: '',
    isCurrent: false,
    isDisabled: false,
  } 
];
```

Validate: `Array`

```js
new SimpleSchema({
  company: { type: String, optional: true },
  uniqueId: { type: Number, optional: true },
  title: { type: String, optional: true },
  description: { type: String, optional: true },
  startDateMonth: { type: String, optional: true },
  startDateYear: { type: String, optional: true },
  endDateMonth: { type: String, optional: true },
  endDateYear: { type: String, optional: true },
  isCurrent: { type: Boolean, optional: true },
  isDisabled: { type: Boolean, optional: true }
}).validate(
  arrayTest
);
```

Update: `Collection`

```js
ProfileCandidate.update({
  _id: "BoDb4Zztq7n3evTqG"
}, {
  $set: {
    careerHistoryPositions: arrayTest
  }
}, (error, result) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log("error: ", "error");
  }
  if (result) {
    console.log("result", result);
  }
});
```

The update appears to work however no data goes into the schema.

Comment: Are you sure that `ProfileCandidate._id` is equal `BoDb4Zztq7n3evTqG`? Do you have `ProfileCandidate` schema validation?

Comment: Yes to the id question. How do I do ProfileCandidate schema validation?

Comment: There are a few different bugs in both meteor-simple-schema and node-simple-schema (I don't know which you are using) that talk about problems similar to this. It may be a bug: 

https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema/issues/159
https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema/issues/157
https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/issues/637

Comment: I think you might be right.